# How to determine which is the latest hook_update_N() function invoked in a Drupal 7 environment

Tags: drush, updating

I have written my first [deployment_module](http://dcycleproject.org/blog/44/what-site-deployment-module) for a Drupal 7 site and installed it into a virtual host on my development server.

I would like to check to see if my hook_update_N() functions have been invoked correctly and so am wondering how to determine which is the latest hook_update_N() function invoked in a Drupal 7 environment.

I imagine some Drush command would be easiest way to find out. Failing that, it is probably set in the database somewhere.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's in the system table. This query:

```
SELECT schema_version FROM system WHERE name='mymodule';
```

will let you know the last update hook successfully completed.

if you want to use drush, there's drush sql-query

```
drush sql-query "SELECT schema_version FROM system WHERE name='mymodule'"
```

Comment: I have tried this and it seems to have worked. Thanks.